# For each loop with submitting form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Model Room:

```
public class Room
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string NumberRoom { get; set; }
        public double CostPerNight { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

My view model code

```
public class RoomModel
    {
        public IList<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
    }
```

My Razor code:

```
@model hotel.Models.RoomModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("ComfortLevelView", "Category"))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Model.Rooms.Count(); i++)
             {
                     <table class="simple-little-table" cellspacing='0'>
                         <tr>
                             <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.Rooms[i].NumberRoom) </td>
                             <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.Rooms[i].Categoryid)</td>
                             <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.Rooms[i].NumberOfSeats) </td>
                             <td>
                                 @{ var result = Model.Rooms[i].CostPerNight * numberNights; }
                                 <p>@ViewBag.NumberNights ночей</p>:@result
                             </td>
                             <td>
                                 <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Booking" />
                             </td>
                         </tr>
                     </table>
                 </div>
             }
        }
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult ComfortLevelView(int NumberNights, int CategoryId, int NumberPeoples ,DateTime SelectedDate)
        {
            IRoomService roomService = new RoomService();;
            return View(roomService.GetRoomsByCategory(CategoryId, SelectedDate, NumberNights, NumberPeoples));
        }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ComfortLevelView(RoomModel model)
{
    //
}
```

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[Hotel.BusinessObject.Room]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'hotel.Models.RoomModel'.

Comment: You have not addressed any of the multiple errors from your last question!  Your query generates a collection of `Room` objects, not a `RoomModel` object!

Comment: thats also not a for-each loop, it's just a for loop

Comment: There was plenty of help in the last question, this is pointless!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is self explanatory. You have this in your view

```
@model hotel.Models.RoomModel
```

but you pass an instance of `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<Hotel.BusinessObject.Room>` to your view because of this line of code in your controller

```
return View(roomService.GetRoomsByCategory(CategoryId, SelectedDate, NumberNights, NumberPeoples));
```

You need to pass an instance of `RoomModel` instead of `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<Hotel.BusinessObject.Room>`. I would suggest changing your controller code to below

```
public ActionResult ComfortLevelView(int NumberNights, int CategoryId, int NumberPeoples, DateTime SelectedDate)
{
    IRoomService roomService = new RoomService();
    var rooms = roomService.GetRoomsByCategory(CategoryId, SelectedDate, NumberNights, NumberPeoples);

    RoomModel model = new RoomModel();
    model.Rooms = rooms.ToList();

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Yes!!!Its very help me!! But public ActionResult ComfortLevelView(RoomModel model)   //model still null(

Comment: You didn't say anything about model being null in the question and you already accepted my answer. If you have another problem, then you need to [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @Alex, Go back to your last question and read my comments. Nothing can post back to your method because there is nothing to post back. `@Html.DisplayFor()` does not generate form controls.

Comment: then how to display the text? I  tried label,textbox,display

Comment: how postback this parameters?

Comment: or I need hiddenfor fields?

Comment: @Alex, please don't keep asking more and more questions in the comments. You have already accepted my answer and what you're asking in the comments is already way out of context of this question. Either [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) or go back to [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30234330/1905949) as suggested by Stephen Muecke. You can [edit your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30234330/edit) if necessary.